# Unity - Variable sometimes resetting to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script applied to a few objects that has a class variable defined as:

```
int flickerLayer;
```

In the start method I change it to have the value of 6 by doing:

```
flickerLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("flicker");
```

But once I get into the OnTriggerEnter2D method, the variable will sometimes be 6 and other times be 0. If I log the value of flickerLayer after the start method, it is always 6. Nothing else in my code modifies flickerLayer. I have tried changing it to private just to make sure but that didn't fix it. However, if I set flickerLayer to 6 when I define it rather than using layerMask, it works fine. I'm thinking that for some reason flickerLayer is being set to its default value as if the Start method didn't run. I don't know what else could be happening especially since the other layer variable I have does not have this issue.

Here's the Start method and OnTriggerEnter2D method code if you're curious:

```
bool candleEnabled = true;
GameObject flickerObject;
GameObject staticFlickerObject;
GameObject flameObject;
int layer;
int flickerLayer;
int overlaps = 0;

void Start(){
    flameObject = transform.Find("light_1").gameObject;
    flickerObject = flameObject.transform.Find("flicker").gameObject;
    staticFlickerObject = flickerObject.transform.Find("better_flicker_0").gameObject;
    layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("flame");
    flickerLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("flicker");
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){

    if (collider.gameObject.layer != layer && collider.gameObject.layer != flickerLayer) {
        overlaps++;
    }
    
    if(candleEnabled && collider.gameObject.layer != layer && !isParent(collider.gameObject) && collider.gameObject.layer != flickerLayer) {
        toggleLight(false);
    }
    else if(collider.gameObject.layer == layer && canLight()) {
        CandleLightController other = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<CandleLightController>();
        if(other != null & other.isEnabled()) {
            toggleLight(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you know it became 0? If you used any log, please keep them in the code. And if there was a problem for `flickerLayer`, then `layer` should have the same problem.

Comment: You're correct, "layer" was also having the same problems, I just didn't notice since it seemed to behave fine. I had a log at the start of OnTriggerEnter2D that showed it would sometimes be 0 and sometimes be the correct value, 6. I also found that most of the zeros were coming from objects that I had disabled the script on in the editor, so I removed the script component from them. Not sure how the OnTriggerEnter2D method was even activating for a disabled script. It mostly prints 6 now, but it still has the problem of it sometimes being 0.

Comment: You can add `if(!enabled) return;` at the start of OnTriggerEnter2D. This message is sent by trigger collider2D or rigidbody2D, the `enabled` property only controls update messages.